# d.3 dealing with half million entries

Tags: d3.js, data-visualization, large-data

I am trying to load 1/2 million data point to the "simple graph" example. I guess there may be a limit for SVG rendering, because the line is not showing up. Can you advice me on how to deal with this "big" graph?

Thanks

// Here the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style>

path{stroke: steelblue;
    stroke-width: 4
    ;
    fill: none;}

.axis path,
.axis line {fill: none;
            stroke: grey;
            stroke-width: 2.5;
            shape-rendering: crispEdges;}

</style>

<h1>FDD Visualization</h1>
<h2>A simple Graph with visual aids using d3</h2>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="d3/d3.v3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"></script>

  <script>

var margin = {top: 50, right: 20, bottom: 50, left: 50},
    width = 1020 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 580 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d").parse;

var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
    .orient("bottom").ticks(5);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
    .orient("left").ticks(5);

var valueline = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.timestamp); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.temperature); });

var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top +")")
        .attr("fill",function(d){return"rgb(0,100,10)";} );

// Get the data
d3.csv("data/data_2.csv", function(error, data) 
{data.forEach(function(d) 
    {d.timestamp = parseDate(d.timestamp);
     d.temperature = +d.temperature;});

    // Scale the range of the data
    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.timestamp; }));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.temperature; })]);

    svg.append("path")      // Add the valueline path.
        .attr("d", valueline(data));

    svg.append("g")         // Add the X Axis
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

    svg.append("g")         // Add the Y Axis
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis);

});

</script>
</body>
```

// Here the data (only first rows...it amounts for approx. 500,000 rows)

```
timestamp,temperature
01/01/1900,23
02/01/1900,13
03/01/1900,13
04/01/1900,15
05/01/1900,12
06/01/1900,24
07/01/1900,12
08/01/1900,19
09/01/1900,12
10/01/1900,16
11/01/1900,16
12/01/1900,19
13/01/1900,24
14/01/1900,12
15/01/1900,20
16/01/1900,20
etc...
```

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a rendering limit, but a screen doesn't have half a million pixels. Also, if I understand your data, you have one point by day since 1900, that's it about 42,000 to the current day. You may want to group your data somehow (by months, average temperature?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing displays because your dates aren't being [parsed](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting) correctly.

Your dates looks like this:

```
16/01/1900
```

but `parseDate` is using the format specifier:

```
"%Y-%m-%d"
```

Fixing this issue just requires a one line change:

```
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d/%m/%Y").parse;
```

A suggestion: use the [dev console](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging) to debug things! Trying to run your script shows an error:

```
Error: Problem parsing d="MNaN,20.000000000000057LNaN,220LNaN,220LNaN, ... "
```

which doesn't look like is has anything to do with trying to display too many values. Inspecting the data array, all the temperature values are `undefined` after `parseDate` is called on them.

Finally, I think Pablo's advice about not trying to show a line graph w/ 500,000 points is solid. Our screens and eyes don't have a high enough resolution to make that a useful display

Comment: Thanks Adam, I reload the previous file in excel and it changed me the "-" by the "/" so I didn't notice the change...Thanks for the dev console suggestion, I was using firebug, but didn't point me any error here so far...

Comment: Athough I changed it to the right format and the parsing error still continues... ;-(

Comment: It's working on my computer; does this work for you? https://github.com/1wheel/learning/tree/master/stacktest/d.3%20dealing%20with%20half%20million%20entries

Comment: Thanks Adam. It is still not working, changed time formatting, tried with more tipes of format etc... not even with a 10 rows data file. I got exactly the same error in your dev console ..;-( Thanks!!

Comment: Thanks Adam. I tried with your code and it worked. I was comparing my code with yours with the exact data file also using Notepad ++ Comapre plug-in, changed line per line untill it matched exactly the working code, and it didn't work...So I got rid of the file, there maybe some issue with formats that escape a "code" problem :-( . By the way, the 1/2 million data entries could be loaded at a reasonable time. Now it comes to learn SVG rendering concepts (very thin lines become black, regardless the color specified). Regards. Luis.

Comment: That's rough with the file : /, glad you got it working eventually. Loading and using lots of data isn't the issue - http://square.github.io/crossfilter/ - meaningfully displaying it on a physical screen is w/o aggregration is.